# Computing small time differences in Singapore adds 30 minutes when converted to hh:mm:ss.mmm

Tags: perl, timezone, timezone-offset

I have this Perl script where I need to monitor the execution time of DBI calls.

In Europe (France), I have no problem:  2 seconds execution time is reported 2 seconds.

This same script running on a computer in Singapore reports 30 minutes and 2 seconds.

Why ?

```
use strict;
use Time::Format qw(%time);
use Time::HiRes qw(gettimeofday);

my $time_start = gettimeofday();

sleep 2;  # some action goes here

my $stat_perf = gettimeofday() - $time_start;
print STDOUT $time{'mm:ss.mmm', $stat_perf} . " \n";
```

The output in France is

```
00:02.000
```

The same script running in Singapore yields:

```
30:02.001
```

Why ?

Answer (score 2):

According to [this documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html#gettimeofday-%28%29), the `gettimeofday` function returns seconds or microseconds since the unix epoch, which is 1/1/1970 **UTC**.  Because it is in UTC, it is not affected by time zones at all.

Also, in your original code you are just using `gettimeofday`, which is going to be returning timestamps from *now*, not from 1970.  But in your suggested answer, for some reason, you have hard-set the timestamp, which won't help you do much.

Yes, there is history to just about every time zone, including Singapore.  [You can see it in the TZDB here](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/master/asia#L2416-2429).  But you are incorrect about it being +8:30 at the epoch. It was actually +7:30.  [You can verify also on this site](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=19700101T00&p1=185&p2=236).  But it doesn't matter anyway because like I said, `gettimeofday` works strictly in UTC.

I think the problem is in how you are interpreting the results.  You have as your last line:

```
print STDOUT $time{'mm:ss.mmm', $stat_perf} . " \n";
```

But `$stat_perf` is the elapsed duration of time, not a value that you can treat as a timestamp.  You probably shouldn't be passing it to `$time`, since that *will* use the local time zone and be expecting a full timestamp.

Also, you may want to use `tv_interval`, as shown [in the examples](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html#EXAMPLES).

#### Update

I searched through the CPAN archives and I'm sure somewhere there is a module for formatting an elapsed duration of time, but I can't seem to find it.  Anyway, it's not too hard to write this on your own.  Here, this should work:

```
my $min = $stat_perf / 60;
my $sec = ($stat_perf * 1000 % 60000) / 1000;
my $elapsed = sprintf("%02u:%06.3f", $min, $sec);
print STDOUT $elapsed . "\n";
```

Comment: I don't think you're getting what is the problem I have to solve: I need to have a string representing minutes, seconds and microseconds of sometime very short times. `gettimeofday` provides me the desired level of granularity. `tv_interval` doesn't do conversion to string in sexagesimal format. Until I'm wrong, `$time{}` gets me the job done. Still, in Singapore, whatever the method I use to get that elapsed time; `print STDOUT $time{'mm:ss.mmm',0};` yields `30:00.000`. `gettimeofday` is not involved here.

Comment: As you pointed out, `$time{}` handles it as a timestamp. Nothing new; hence the trick I posted. So far I've not found a better way of getting - anywhere on the planet - 67.934 seconds converted into "01:07.934". Any suggestion?

Comment: I'll look to see if I can find (or write) a script for emitting an elapsed time formatted in that format.  But do realize that by treating it as a time of day you've also got a problem that a value like 65 minutes is going to be treated as 1 hour and 5 minutes, and since you're not showing hours, you will just see 5 minutes.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, this is what I need: Over an hour duration is captured elsewhere (job killed by watchdog actually). From the commenter's inputs here, I do believe that I would better write my own real-to- sexagesimal converter, dropping eventually what's above 3600s. More soon for your reviewing.

Answer (score 0):

The anser is ...

Singapore is now 08h00 offset from UTC. In 1970, it was offset by 08h30. Asking for the conversion of a few seconds into a string will get us to 1970, not today's date, and timezone.

By requesting

```
print STDOUT $time{'mm:ss.mmm', 2} . " \n";
```

the system adjusts to 1970 (epoch) timezone offset.

In order to get a correct result in Singapore, we must shift to after 1982, when Singapore made its last timezone change.

```
print STDOUT $time{'mm:ss.mmm', 2 + 1356994800} . " \n";
```

as

```
UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-01-01 00:00:00')  = 1356994800
```

We are only concerned by the time of day portion of the date, so this does it.

Check with

```
zdump -v Asia/Singapore
```

This is the trick.

Comment: Or maybe you shouldn't treat a duration as a date-time.  Despite its name, `%time` really is a date-time formatter.

Comment: Are there any other function(s) but `$time{}` that can get 67.934 seconds converted into "01:07.934" anywhere on the planet? Any suggestion .. beside coding a real-to-sexagesimal converted? However, I don't see anything unrealistic in the trick I've proposed, beside it's performance in terms of cpu cycles consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that emulates `$time{}` in converting a real number into a string representing the `mm:ss` sexagesimal conversion of its integer part, concatenated with the decimal remainder formatted as microseconds.

As this is going to be part of a library, there are protections set to avoid invoking it with bad arguments.

I hope I didn't miss something.

```
use strict;
use Time::Format qw(%time);


# ----------------------------------------------------------
# A substitute to $time{} as we have issues with TZ offsets at epoch days in some part of the World
# A real to sexagesimal converter
# Format will be set to match $time{'mm:ss.mmm', $stat_perf};
sub microTime {
  return '' unless (my ($intertime) = @_);
  return '' unless (ref ($intertime) eq '');
  return '' unless (sprintf("%s", $intertime) =~ m/^(?:[\d]+)(?:\.(?:[\d]+))?$/);
  my $intNum = int($intertime);
  "a" =~ /a/; # Resets regex buffers
  sprintf ("%.03f", $intertime - $intNum) =~ m,\.([\d]+),;
  my $intDec = $1;  # It's always defined
  my $intUnder = $intNum % 3600;
  my $intMin = int($intUnder / 60);
  my $intSec = $intUnder % 60;
  return sprintf ("%02d:%02d.%03d", $intMin, $intSec, $intDec);
}


  my $stat_perf;

  $stat_perf = 345.987;
  $stat_perf = 345;
  $stat_perf = 3945.987;
  $stat_perf = 0;
  $stat_perf = 3945.918733;


  print STDOUT sprintf (" >> %s\n", &microTime ($stat_perf));
  print STDOUT sprintf (" == %s\n", $time{'mm:ss.mmm', $stat_perf});
```